# How to customize Windows 7 taskbar using registry entries?

Tags: windows-7, windows, taskbar

I am trying to find registry entries to set the following conditions:

- Auto-hide task bar
- Use small icons on task bar
- Disable icon grouping (never combine)

Google seems unforthcoming maybe someone here knows how to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Use Small Icons**

> Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
>
> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced]
>
> "TaskbarSmallIcons"=dword:00000001

For small icons,set the dWord value to 1.

---

**Disable Icon Grouping**

Navigate to

> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced]
> "TaskbarGlomming"

is what you're looking for.

Comment: I've removed the link because [it has a mostly bad rating at "Web of Trust" and could be engaged into malicious activity](http://www.mywot.com/de/scorecard/liutilities.com). Can you guarantee that the site is safe?

Comment: No...I can't guarantee that fact.

Comment: Sorry. Site has good info as well as unwanted links, unfortunately. Apologies for linking.

Comment: Then perhaps, you ought to decide this to be the correct answer to your question. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

For our deployments, we Setup a machine the way we wanted, then exported the binary key: HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Taskband.  Its all binary, and kind of nasty, but we use Group Policy Preferences to force it to copy down once, which sets our "default" behavior for all Windows 7 Machines on our domain.

Comment: Did you do this in audit mode or simply in a normal installation?

Comment: This is dangerous - permissions will be wrong on that HIVE, and it will cause problems over time (not right away, but eventually).